# Is there Comprehensive view on snap related and Ubuntu evolution?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

`Xenial 16.04` arrived with preinstalled `snapd` package along with classic `apt/deb` packaging system.

I've also observed these terms `snap`, `snappy`, `Ubuntu core` and `snappy Ubuntu core` appeals interchangeably.

Is there thoughtfully Comprehensive view on all of them ? Are they paving the way for the future of `Ubuntu` evolution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu core: minimal install of Ubuntu

Snappy: snappy(cleverly concise; neat.) ;P name for new packaging system

Snappy Ubuntu Core: minimal install of Ubuntu + plus Snap packages

A "snap": is a package

snapd: environment for installing snaps

---

Yes they are paving the way for the future of Ubuntu - as the traditional deb files have already been phased out for apps that are "paid" or closed source in the software center.

These snaps are now able to be built for the desktop version of ubuntu - as well as "Snappy Ubuntu Core" which is built more for internet of things applications or purpose built servers.

In the future they say the ubuntu phone, as well as unity 8 on the desktop will make use of snaps.

---

Since you mention xenial - you probably mean the desktop snaps at this moment - so at this point the terms aren't quite interchangeable. Snappy and Ubuntu Core probably are mostly referring to the IOT version - (Mark himself explaining video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlcTDz9ogug)

Where "snaps" on the Desktop is just the packaging system, but is still really intriguing when it comes to versions/dependencies/updates a good example is the Krita snap https://uappexplorer.com/app/krita.krita

Comment: I goolged `Ubuntu core` solely but it showed me `Snappy Ubuntu core` voluntarily.

Comment: they are mostly inseparable now - but there used to be  "Ubuntu Core" before snappy - thus a "Core" installation of ubuntu - just the essentials + the Snappy packaging built in

Comment: this has even caused confusion with tags on this site... http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12357/tag-synonym-request-snappy-ubuntu-core

Answer (score 1):

Please review [snapcraft.io](http://snapcraft.io/docs/) for a detailed look at these.